# "Page not Found" error when trying to edit Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-edit

I went to my profile page on AskUbuntu so that I could edit my Network Profile, But when I press `Edit` I am getting a "Page not Found' error.

[image]

Comment: Yup, reproduced here on MSE as well.

Comment: Digging, stand by.

Comment: @AnnaLear I have reproduced it on [so],[su],[ham.se], and [raspberrypi.se] as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, looks like a change I made on Jan 8th just bit us hard here.

I moved some route registrations around, deleting some obsolete code. So we now have two routes '/users/edit/{userid}', one for POST, one for GET (just like we have had all this time), only they have *different* method names now.

And on a recent push, when the route table was rebuilt, the GET route ended up not being registered, hence the 404.

Which seems to have been just luck of the draw, given that it didn't happen for about a month and a half.

This is fixed and has been pushed across the network.